# Can an estate be distributed against the will when all parties are in agreement?

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates, probate

I am learning about estates, wills, and probate courts. I am wondering about the following situation and procedures that may follow:

> Beneficiary 1 (or B1), the sole beneficiary stated on a will, was awarded an entire estate after the benefactor's death. B1 has a good relationship with their two siblings. B1 and the two siblings all had a mutual understanding that the estate should be divided into thirds and distributed accordingly. It was also the benefactor's intention to do so, but not explicitly stated in the will. The assets in the estate are solely investment accounts and no real estate property.

What could the three individuals consider to split the estate up in this fashion?

Any information to learn about this subject would be appreciated!

Comment: Surely this is just the sole beneficiary deciding what to do with their new found inheritance after they become entitled to it?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Moo so that is one way to look at it as the sole beneficiary has the estate. However, the intentions were really to split by thirds and distribute. This obviously wasn't expressed formally, but it is the intention to effectively transfer 2/3's of the estate to the two siblings--as if it were inherited from the estate.

Comment: B1 probably has to file a gift tax return, if this is a gift, but that's not required with a real inheritance. Dunno if "benefactor's intent" renders this an inheritance.

Comment: Wondering if all siblings could dispute the will (including the now sole beneficiary) and then divide up the estate through inheritance, instead of a gift from the sole beneficiary

Comment: @Jasonp can the estate holders intent be shown in any concrete form other than the will?

Comment: @Moo if you're referring to the current holder of the estate, yes. If you're referring to the dead benefactor, no.

Comment: @Moo the sole beneficiary gifting a portion of the estate would be a separate operation from the inheritance and so it could be subject to different taxes. Also, the sole beneficiary would count as having received the whole estate, again with the legal and fiscal obligations that it could entail.

Comment: I believe the main objective is to avoid gifting the inherited estate. Instead, somehow challenge the directives from the will to allow all three parties to inherit their third of the estate--thus avoiding tax implications from gifting. It would be interesting if the sole beneficiary could express that the estate should have been distributed differently.

Answer (score 1):

> What could the three individuals consider to split the estate up in
> this fashion?

If there is an agreement of all interested parties they can do almost anything. But, only to the extent that it isn't to the detriment of creditors of the estate who aren't paid in full without their consent.